# Wordpress How To Use Templates From Main Page(s) in Custom Post Type(s)

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

Asked on WordPress Development Overflow [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/171952/page-templates-used-in-custom-post-type) first. The same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492233/hierarchical-custom-post-type-not-show-page-template-list-in-page-attributes) with no real response. They claim it's not possible but I have used plugins that accomplish this.

In WordPress I am having a problem figuring out how to use the default page post type templates in my custom post type and I think I am using the wrong search keywords everywhere because I having no luck...

I have a client that requested an "easy-to-maintain" method of displaying two other languages of their site. They said that a translator is out of the question because a lot of their context uses subtle slangs that only are used within certain communities of people.

I figured the easiest way to make a visible and friendly method of entry would be to accompany their current "pages" post type with two more of those language names. Problem is that their main "pages" post type has a drop down menu with a choice of four templates. I cannot seem to get their new post types to include these as well.

I have tried adding in the `single-name.php` and `archive-name.php` but this gives me only one of those four types, which is expected, I do understand that much. However, I have used plugins and themes that have custom post type templates in a drop down so I know its do-able. My post_type has all the usual stuff turned on i.e. ...

```
'capability_type' => 'page',
'hierarchical' => true,
'supports' => array('title','editor','custom-fields','page-attributes')
```

I also need to know if anyone who does know what to do here would suggest just simply making a custom meta box that looks for the page template stuff? Or is there a much smoother WordPress related function that I can use?

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are confusing custom post types with custom page templates. If you have a custom post type of 'cars' then the template with the file name `archive-cars.php` will show all the cars posts and `single-cars.php` will show a single cars post.

You are asking about page templates. You can call those whatever you like, the important thing is that for them to appear in the page template dropdown you need to include a specific piece of code in the head of the template;

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/
```

See the codex for more information;

http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template

Comment: yes I know all this. The problem is that I can only have one template type because file systems only allow one thing to be named the same. I cant have single-cars.php showing up four times in my file system each with the proper template name I need in the comments. It seems the only way to have WordPress recognize templates for custom post types is naming the files single-something.php and using the comments to declare a template name. What I need for cars (for example) is say four templates like suv, sedan, truck or van... I need the four templates from my page templates.

Comment: the main page post types dont require naming all the page templates single-something.php you can just use the comments template name and it shows up "auto-magically"

Comment: also I could use some help with the heuretic. Its due yesterday and I have brain mush from trying to think about 10 things at once :)

Comment: Ouch - I see what you mean now.  Custom templates for custom post types.  Not sure on that one but looking at it I'd say additional taxonomies required there to split them out.  Categories within custom post type.